# Autofac xml configuration for addons

Tags: c#, autofac, assembly-loading

In order to better understand how I can use Autofac with json/xml configuration, I'm creating a small sample application that will support addons. The solution contains the following assemblies: (1) BusinessLogic.Interfaces, (2) BusinessLogic1, (3) BusinessLogic2, (4) DependencyInjection, and (5) Views. The latter is a simple Winforms assembly that I can use to test the application.

Assembly 'BusinessLogic.Interfaces' contains only one interface, IFoo. The two BusinessLogic assemblies both contain only one type, Foo, which both implement IFoo. With this setup, I can configure the DI container to give me an appropriate implementation of IFoo. Following the documentation on [Autofac site](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/configuration/xml.html), I get the following code for reading the configuration file

```
private static ContainerBuilder CreateBuilderFromConfigFile()
{
    var config = new configurationBuilder();
    config.AddJsonFile("autofac.json"); //BTW, requires m_a_n_y nuget packages
    var module = new ConfigurationModule(config.Build());
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterModule(module);
    return builder;
}
```

with the following configuration

```
{
  "components": [{
     "type": "BusinessLogic2.Foo, BusinessLogic.Interfaces",
     "services": [{
        "type": "BusinessLogic.Interfaces.IFoo, BusinessLogic.Interfaces"
    }]
  }]
}
```

In Class DependencyInjection.DiContainer, I use

```
 public void Initialize(Containerbuidler builder)
 {
     Container = builder.Build(); //definition 'Container' not shown here
 }
```

When assembly View is linked to BusinessLogic1 and BusinessLogic2, this code works. In the json file I can easily change which implementation to use.

If I remove BusinessLogic2 from the references of the View assembly, I run into problems. I get an InvalidOperationExecption on the command 'builder.Build()'. That is reasonable as the requested type is in an assembly that has not been loaded. Therefore I load assemblies using reflection. Following [this tutorial](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Creating-a-simple-plugin-b6174b62) , I have added the following method

```
private static void LoadAddons(string searchInFolder, string pattern)
{
   foreach(var fileName in Directory.GetFiles(searchInFolder, pattern))
   {
      Assembly.LoadFrom(fileName);
   }
}
```

Now, in the main method, I first call method LoadAddons and subsequently CreateBuidlerFromConfigFile. In the Modules view of Visual Studio (Debug -> Windows -> Modules) I see that BusinessLogic2 has been loaded, but still there is an InvalidOperationException.

**Edit** The exception message is: 
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in Autofac.Configuration.dll
Additional information: The type 'BusinessLogic2.Foo, BusinessLogic' could not be found. It may require assembly qualification, e.g. "MyType, MyAssembly".
How do I tell Autofac, configured using xml/json, to register a type that is dynamically loaded?"

Comment: It should works. Are you using the following string `BusinessLogic2.Foo, BusinessLogic.Interfaces` in your configuration file ? assembly name looks like the wrong one. Are you sure the assembly is loaded ? Could you share the exact error message ?

Comment: @CyrilDurand I've edited the original question to include the exception message. Also, without modifying the autofac.json file, I made it work by linked the View assembly to BusinessLogic2. So when assemblies are tied together at compile time, it works, whereas Autofac registration using assemblies that are dynamically loaded causes problems. One strange thing; in the Modules view I see that BusinessLogic2 is loaded, but BusinessLogic1 is not listed although assembly View is linked to it (i.e. linked during compilation)

Comment: Which kind of application are you doing ? ASP.net MVC ? WPF ? `Autofac` will only do `Type.GetType("BusinessLogic.Interfaces.IFoo, BusinessLogic.Interfaces")` if you try this code after the manual assembly loading, is it working ? if you try directly from the loaded assembly (assembly.LoadType("...")) is it working ?

Comment: @CyrilDurand You may be onto something. When trying your suggeston, i.e. getting the type of the interface, I get a result. But `Type.GetType("BusinessLogic2.Foo, BusinessLogic2")` , which tries to get the type of the concrete implementation, returns null. Warrants a further investigation

Comment: I finally figured out after having checked out the sources and debugged Autofac. The issue is that Autofac.Configuration the method `GetAssembly(this IConfiguration,string)` tries to load an assembly that was located in a different folder than that of the executing assembly. By copying assembly BusinessLogic2 to the bin folder of the executing assembly, everything worked.